# Finding all different adjacent ranges matching/covering a specific range in a specific order

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I want to find out all the adjacent ranges matching/covering a target range in a specific order. For e.g.

Given range is 5-12

Source ranges are

1-7

1-13

4-8

4-12

5-7

5-8

5-12

5-13

7-12

8-12

So the results should be with the priority as following

```
1. 5-12 (Exact match)
2. 5-7,7-12 (Two Adjacent ranges match)[Ranges Start And End Exact Match]
2. 5-8,8-12 (Two Adjacent ranges match)[Ranges Start And End Exact Match]
3. 5-13 (Single Covering range)[Range Start Exact Match]
3. 4-12 (Single Covering range)[Range End Exact Match]
3. 4-8,8-12 (Two Adjacent ranges covering)[Range End Exact Match]
3. 1-7,7-12 (Two adjacent ranges covering)[Range End Exact Match]
4. 1-13 (Single Covering range)[No Ranges Start And End Exact Match]
```

Any help will be highly valued.

Comment: Are you legitimately using .NET 2.0 or is that just a tag you chose? The answers could vary based on that

Comment: Also I am having a very hard time understanding the logic you are actually looking for based on your example, and if you could post some code you have tried it would be helpful

Comment: Ah okay, some people throw any tag at their question so I was just checking. I reread your question a couple of time and now understand what logic you want, but i still think you should post some code that you have written to show you tried to come up with your own algorithm. This is not a site for people to do your work for you

Comment: Actually, I am thinking of the algorithm as follows

a) Find all the adjacent combinations

b) Find single source ranges which are covering the whole target range

c) Prioritize the ranges according to Single exact match, Adjacent Ranges Start and End exact match and so on.

But I am ashamed that I am going no where. Just needs the direction of storing the adjacent ranges and working on them :(

Comment: Sorry, new to this site. Do not know how the formatting works. Accidentally post the incomplete comment.

Comment: You could have an object that is a range and how many subranges were used to form it. This generalizes to any number of combinations, and allows you to sort by number of subranges. If you need you could also store the subranges in a list in that object as well if that is important

Answer (score 0):

first create a class for the Range

```
class Range{
   public int start;
   public int end;
   public Range(int start, int end){
      this.start=start;
      this.end=end;
   }
   public string toString(){
      return start+"-"+end;
   }
}
```

after creating such, create this method somewhere.

```
public static void classifyRanges(Range sourceRange, Range[]ranges){
   foreach(Range range in ranges){
      if(range.start==sourceRange.start && range.end==range.end){
         Console.WriteLine("1."+range.toString()+" (Exact Match)";
      }
   }
   foreach(Range range in ranges){
      if(range.start!=sourceRange.start && range.end!=range.end){
         Console.WriteLine("4."+range.toString()+" (No Match)";
      }
   }
}
```

Still formulating the others though